# How to get back the previous/old editor in wp admin in updated version >5

Tags: wordpress, editor, admin, wordpress-5

Wp updated version >5 is creating a problem in wp admin editor, is there any way to switch the editor to the previous one ?

Comment: search for "classic editor" plugin

Comment: Thanks @DaFois, I think Disable Gutenberg plugin is better, but still will give a try on classic editor. Lets see which works better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below plugin.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-gutenberg/

Comment: Thanks, will definitely try this plugin.